# the intersection of inductive sets is a set

Tags: set-theory

In these notes 
http://home.fau.edu/wmcgove1/web/Courses/Ntransitive.pdf
Definition 1.3 it is said that the intersection of inductive sets is itself inductive.

A set $A$ is inductive if: $(\emptyset \in A) \land (n \in A \implies n^+ := n \cup \{n\} \in A)$.

I think we cannot say that the class of all inductive sets is itself a set (can we?).

So what we really want to prove is that if $A$ and $B$ are inductive sets then $(A\subset B) \lor (B\subset A)$ so that if an inductive set $A$ actually exists (this is eventually guaranteed by an appropriate axiom) then every inductive set either contains $A$ or is contained in $A$ and the intersection of all inductive subset of $A$ is itself inductive and hence is the smallest inductive set.

If this is correct the question is: how do we prove that either $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$?

Comment: You don't, because it's not true. But you don't need it to be true, either, because if there's one inductive set, then separation is enough to give you the minimal inductive set.

Comment: Wrong question. We can't prove that either $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A.$ We can prove that the intersection of any set of inductive sets is inductive, and in particular the intersection of any two inductive sets is inductive. It follows that, if $A$ is an inductive set, and if $C$ is the intersection of all inductive subsets of $A,$ then $C$ is also the intersection of all the inductive sets in the world. Because, if $D$ is any other inductive set, then $A\cap D$ is an inductive subset of $A,$ so $C\subset A\cap D\subset D.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove that every two inductive sets satisfy $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

What you can prove, however, is that the intersection of any number of inductive sets is an inductive set. From this we can conclude that if $B$ is *an* inductive set, then there is a *smallest* inductive set $A$ such that $A\subseteq B$: simply take the intersection of all the inductive subsets of $B$.

But now I claim even more, this $A$ is in fact a subset of *any* inductive set. To see why, simply note that if $C$ is an inductive set, then $B\cap C$ is an inductive subset of $B$, and therefore $A\subseteq B\cap C$. This $A$ is in fact $\omega$, the least infinite ordinal.

Now, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha$ is an inductive set. But also $V_\alpha$, the $\alpha$th stage of the von Neumann hierarchy is an inductive set. Take any limit ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $|V_\alpha|<|\beta|$, and you have two inductive sets which are not subsets of one another. (And it follows also that the class of inductive sets is not a set, indeed.)

Comment: Thanks, now things are much clearer... Indeed what I really was trying to prove is that if $x,y\in \omega$ then either $x \subset y$ or $y\subset x$ and tried to reduce this to the (false) property stated in the question. How can I prove this property of natural numbers?

Comment: How did you define $\omega$? Do you have the tools of ordinals and induction?

Comment: $\omega$ (I would call it $\mathbb N$) is given by axiom as a minimal inductive set (hence *the* minimal inductive set) as in your answer.

Comment: Yes, but what properties and tools do you have already? Induction?

Comment: I have ZF axioms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory

Comment: Yes, but what have you proved from them already? Did you define the ordinals? Did you prove anything about $\in$-induction? There is a toolkit for doing set theory, and I'm asking how many of the usual tools do you already have in yours. Regardless, since I am going to be slightly less available over the next few days (I'll be here, but not entirely focused), you should (1) look for questions about this specific thing (and there had been a couple, I'm sure); and if none of them helps you, (2) ask the question you wanted help with explicitly.

Comment: I don't know what $\in$-induction is. I know little about ordinals. I would like to understand how to get natural numbers (and Peano axioms) out of ZF (or   ZFC if needed). Maybe I'm missing some keywords to find the relevant material on internet.